# How to use getSystemService in a non-activity class?

Tags: android, android-context

I am building an application which triggers an alarm via AlarmManager.

I would like to be able to call the Alarm via it's own non-activity class, but since I am not extending Activity, I don't appear to have any 'context'. This concept confuses me, and I've read the sdk docs.

How would I go about using:

```
alarmTest = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

in my non-activty class?

Also, I'm assuming getting context will allow me to use SharedPrefs and Intents in my non-activity class as well?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can pass the context to the non-activity class which is the preferred way or you could encapsulate the base context of the application to a singleton which would allow you to access the context anywhere within the application. At some cases this might be a good solution but in others its certainly not a good one.

Anyway, if you want to trigger an alarm via the `AlarmManager` I'm pretty sure the alarm should inherit from a `Service` or better yet from `IntentService` and in such cases you have access to the context via `this.getBaseContext()` or `this.getApplicationContext()`

Comment: Is it advisable to pass context? Doesn't that lead to context leak?

Answer (score 21):

`Service` and `Activity` inherit from `Context` - so when you are calling `getSystemService` in these classes, you are really calling `super.getSystemService`.

If you want to have a `Context` available in another class, you can pass one as an argument to a method of that class, keep a reference to it, etc.

**Edit**: Code sample. But seriously, it is *extremely* basic - if you understand inheritance and methods.

```
class MyActivity extends Activity { // Activity extends Context, so MyActivity also extends Context
  void someMethod() {
    MyOtherClass.useStaticContext(this);
    MyOtherClass instance = new MyOtherClass();
    instance.useInstanceContext(this.getApplicationContext());
  }
}
class MyOtherClass {
  static void useStaticContext(Context context) {
  }
  void useInstanceContext(Context context) {
  }
}
```

Comment: I think I understand what you mean. Would you happen to know where I could find sample code of this in a repo? Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

You can try the following, it allows you to get the current context the view is running through.

```
alarmTest = (AlarmManager)this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
```

Comment: How do you do this in Kotlin?

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass a context into the non-activity class.

Answer (score 1):

Use this
in Activity:

```
private Context context = this;

........
if(Utils.isInternetAvailable(context){
Utils.showToast(context, "toast");
}
..........
```

in Utils:

```
public class Utils {

    public static boolean isInternetAvailable(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();
    }

    public static void showToast(Context context, String text) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```