# solution for getSystemService function at Android

Tags: java, android

I want to test something about usb devices, I try to write a small program, I am sure that it is wrong but this is not the point of this question. 
I am sure that my imports are OK but the Android Studio refused to build this class with an error about the GetSystemService(). I have the message:

> Error:(65, 43) error: cannot find symbol method getSystemService(String).

I used also an example from http://android-er.blogspot.de/2013/10/list-attached-usb-devices-in-usb-host.html and the Android Studio also has the same error but if i install the Apk from this website then it is running on my device, so i supposed that something is wrong at Android Studio. 
Any good idea?

OFFTOPIC "QT Creator is light years better"

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbManager;
import android.hardware.usb.UsbAccessory;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileDescriptor;
import android.util.Log;


public class DeviceOpenActivity {

private static final String TAG = "DeviceOpenActivity";

UsbManager usbManager = (UsbManager) getSystemService(Context.USB_SERVICE);
UsbAccessory mAccessory;
ParcelFileDescriptor mFileDescriptor;
FileInputStream mInputStream;
FileOutputStream mOutputStream;

 public static int fibonacci(int n) {
   if (n<2) return n;
   return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2);
}

private void openAccessory() {
    Log.d(TAG, "openAccessory: " + mAccessory);

    mFileDescriptor = usbManager.openAccessory(mAccessory);
    if (mFileDescriptor != null) {
        FileDescriptor fd = mFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();
        mInputStream = new FileInputStream(fd);
        mOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(fd);
    }
   }
}
```

Comment: please learn java(or any modern oo language) first ... your class has no such method ...

Comment: This is a non-activity class, refer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4141555/how-to-use-getsystemservice-in-a-non-activity-class

Comment: @Selvin i explained that is not the point of the question my Java experience. If i use the code from the above link i have the same error, so it's not my Java skills the problem. :-)

Comment: not possible at all ... base clase from the example is defining this method ... so yes, it is a problem with basic OOP's poblems(class hierarchy)

Comment: I want to use this class in a QT App for Android, i am not sure if i can change the Activity Class in QT because is auto generated. So i lost every time my changes. Now i try to learn how to use some extra java code in QT Apps

Comment: check the doc ... it is a method of Context class ... you need to use it with Context instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you check the example that you provided, you will verify that there is a `MainActivity` class that extends `Activity` class, which by its turn extends indirectly from Context. In order to call `getSystemService()` you need to have an available `Context`. If you make your `DeviceOpenActivity` extend `Activity`, Android Studio will not complain anymore about your call.

Just leave your class declaration like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
```

Don't forget that you need to provide a XML layout for your `Activity`, as well as the `Activity` methods, like `onCreate()`.

Comment: Can u please explain more about "Don't forget that you need to provide a XML layout for your Activity, as well as the Activity methods, like onCreate()" ?

Comment: The example you provided has everything there, including the XML layout and the Activity code. Just add the code you missed from MainActivity to your Activity.